# Running a simple VBA script to test a connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to test the connection of a GoDaddy SQL Server database.  I'm getting an 'invalid connection string attribute.'

What's wrong with this script?

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim canConnect As Boolean

Public Sub TestConnection()

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection   
    cnn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=GoDaddyServer.com;Initial Catalog=dBase1;UserID=userID; Password='password';"   
    If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
        canConnect = True
        cnn.Close
    End If   
MsgBox canConnect

End Sub
```

Comment: @ the Original Poster, if one of the answers below solved your problem (and it sounds like it did), don't forget to green-check it for future people who stumble on this post with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, you have to specify the Provider property outside the connection string like so:

```
Dim conn
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Provider = "sqloledb"
conn.Open "Data Source=GoDaddyServer.com; Initial Catalog=dbase1; User ID=userid; Password=pass;"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working.  The key was placing the connection string in a separate object and passing that string to the connection object. The other key was changing the User ID parameter to 'Uid'.  That's required for the 'Provider=sqloledb;

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a password quoted in a SQL Server connection string like you have.  Try removing the quotes:

```
"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=GoDaddyServer.com;Initial Catalog=dBase1;User ID=userID; Password=password;"
```

You might find [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) useful in the future.

Comment: you're right.  I took the tick marks off the password.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can specify the provider direct within the connection string

```
Dim cnn as ADODB.Connection
Dim cnn_str as String
cnn_str = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=PASSWORD"
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open cnn_str
```